# Stochastic process independent of its future

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Are there examples of predictable stochastic processes $X$ such that their past is independent of their future?
More formally, such that $\sigma\{X_s | s\in (0,t]\}$ is independent of $\sigma\{X_s | s\in (t,u)\}$ for all $0<t<u$?

Of course the process cannot have right continuous paths, but maybe a left-continuous white noise of some form?

Comment: Every Markov Process that is predictable fulfill this condition and this is quite general, for example any diffusion process enjoy this property. Best regards.

Comment: @TheBridge Unfortunately I don't think that's true. Take Brownian motion $W$, you can infer the value of $W_t$ if you know its future after $t$, because of continuity.

Comment: @ AmericanCaller : Sorry I don't get your point and stick to the claim. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge Thanks for your comment.
Take $A$ a Borel set and $X$ right continuous. The event $X_t \in A$ belongs to $\sigma\{ X_s | s\in(0,t]\}$ obviously, and to $\sigma\{ X_s |s\in(t,u)\}$, as $X_t=\lim_{u\downarrow t} X_u$. Hence the two algebras cannot be independent.

Answer (score 1):

How about a process with only two paths: $X^{(1)}_t$ and $X^{(2)}_t$, each has probability of 1/2, and

$X^{(1)} = 0$ at $t=0$,

$X^{(2)} = 1$ at $t=0$,

and both are $1/2$ on $(0\ , 1]$?